# How to Save an Order Without Processing payment Programatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to add New Order in Magento 2.3.4 I don't want to process payment how I can do this?

Need Help

Answer (score 0):

Without payment method you won't be able to place order, but can use Money Order/ Bank transfer payment method to place order without payment processing at checkout.

Comment: i have payment details... i just want to save order not place order

Comment: Like order draft?

Comment: Yes i have an order that is placed already bit due to some reasons it is not saved in sales_order table... i have all data is quote but not in sales_order table